# In 16.04 in Unity launchpad

Tags: unity, software-center, launchpad

The ubuntu software button gives empty screen for seversal seconds and
then returns to Unity.  Other launch buttons work.
Recently I made changes in appearance using the two Tweaks.

Tried terminal `software-center` got errors  and a version of ubuntu software center that I can access through the dashboard.

The error pages read

```
software-center
/usr/bin/software-center:25: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/purchaseview.py:29: PyGIWarning: WebKit2 was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import WebKit2 as webkit
2016-07-09 14:00:52,037 - softwarecenter.backend.zeitgeist_logger - WARNING - Support for Zeitgeist disabled
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/symbolic_icons.py:23: PyGIWarning: PangoCairo was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('PangoCairo', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib, PangoCairo
2016-07-09 14:00:52,090 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2016-07-09 14:00:53,162 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2016-07-09 14:00:53,166 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2016-07-09 14:00:53,220 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:585: Warning: Source ID 76 was not found when attempting to remove it
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
2016-07-09 14:00:54,268 - softwarecenter.db.update - WARNING - failed to load file /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/videoplayer.py:29: PyGIWarning: Gst was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gst
/usr/bin/software-center:184: Warning: Source ID 146 was not found when attempting to remove it
  Gtk.main()
2016-07-09 14:00:56,394 - softwarecenter.db.update - WARNING - failed to load file /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
2016-07-09 14:00:57,648 - softwarecenter.db.utils - INFO - software-center-agent finished with status 0
```

Comment: Could you please open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), type `software-center` and press Enter? What happens? Are there any error messages? If so, please copy and paste them into your question.

Comment: There's not much specific in there so I'll recommend a re-installation of `software-center` (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center`) and the deletion of the supposedly corrupted cache files mentioned in the log (`sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt-xapian-index`). Does that help?